# Updating Database model (.edmx) Model First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first

I am having a few problems with updating the model in EF using Model First.

I have exhausted my efforts with the suggestions of adding migrations (which is normally done using Code First).

The Package Manager Console prints the message

**Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing DbCompiledModel.**

I have also tried this suggestion

[Updating model in EF Database First project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951040/updating-model-in-ef-database-first-project)

However nothing happens when i click "Run Custom Tool"

Any suggestions please on how to update the model to reflect the changes that have been added to the database.

Comment: are you trying to update your model with existing db ?

Comment: Yes. I have a connection to a (localdb)/v11.0

Comment: if you have already created your model and have data base than my below answer should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your model 
right click and you will find an option Update Model from database

[image]

Click update model from database than a window will open like this:

[image]

So choose the modified table to update them in model.

Comment: Oh my hat .. i feel like a proper n00b. Thanks Afnan