# Entity Framework, Database First, Class File Not Created

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, database-first

I have a pretty complex EF model created from an MS SQL database. (I'm using EF 6.1.0.) I added a table to the database and did "Update Model from Database."  Unfortunately, something went wrong, and while lots of XML was generated in the .edmx file (as seen with the XML editor) for the table and its relationships (all correct and complete, as best I can tell), no class declaration was generated.  When I look under .tt where the .cs files are for all the tables in the model, there is no .cs file for this class. Since the class was already in the .edmx file, I was not able to repeat the "Update Model from Database."

I've added many tables to the model this way in the past, and I can't see what's different about this one.

Here are some of the things I have tried:

- Searched the web, but found nothing that seemed relevant. Most articles were tutorials about using "Update Model from Database."  Here's an example: [Updating model in EF Database First project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951040/updating-model-in-ef-database-first-project)
- Used the XML editor to remove from the .edms file all references to the table, its associations, and Entity Sets. Then I closed VS, rebooted, reopened it, and repeated the "Update Model from Database."  I got the same result.
- Looked in the Model Browser to see if I could delete the class, but it wasn't there.
- Closed all my VS windows. (An article suggested this.)

Does anyone have a suggestion?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's a link table between two other tables, EF does not model this as a table but as a relationship. Is this your case?

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much.

Comment: @JimS So how did you resolve your problem? ([Relevant](https://xkcd.com/979/))

Comment: @AlexL, it's hard to remember after so long. I think I temporarily removed the foreign-key relationships from the new table, and then updating the model from the database gave me what I wanted. I have found it easier to manage many-to-many relationships myself that to try to use Entity Framework for that.

Comment: Thanks @JimS. I looked into my problem closer and [asked new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471588/cant-add-new-tables-to-ef-6).